# Implementation of Atomic wait in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

The following is a translation of an atomic wait in Java. 
Here what is the need for `while`? Isn't `if` sufficient?

```
///<await (condition) statements; > 

synchronized(obj)
{ 
      while ( !condition) 
      { 
         obj.wait();
      }
      statements;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `while`, because just because someone sent you a `notify` does not mean that the condition is now true (or is still true).

All `notify` does (or is supposed to do) is tell the waiting threads (of which there can be many, with different conditions to wait for, even on the same monitor) that now would be a good time to re-evaluate if they still need to `wait`.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually two reasons why you need it.

Firstly, if a monitor owner calls `notifyAll()`, all waiting threads are waken up one after another, so if one of the previous threads changed the condition your assumption about it will be not true anymore.

The second reason is [Spurious wakeup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup). As most JVM implementations rely on operating system threading model and some of them allow spurious wakeups (in sake of performance), you need to be ready to such case.

Comment: I think Doug Lea has commented that students can in a state trying to work out the rare situations when `while` can be removed. With spurious wakeups, you are going to need it, so there is no need for pointless discussions in this area.

Comment: The existence of spurious wake-ups implies that waits should always occur in loops, so my answer does not contradict with what is stated in Doug Lea's "Concurrent Programming in Java" book.